# How to have powershell script execute batch command in same terminal

Tags: windows, powershell, batch-file

I have a powershell 2 script that I'm trying to develop. The purpose of this script is to wrap around a batch script and intelligently choose what version of said batch script to run. Somewhere along the lines in my code I have some logic that goes like this:

```
& $myCommand $args
```

$myCommand is the fully qualified filename of the batch file I want to run. $args is the args passed into this script. This works except it opens up a command window when running $myCommand. How do I prevent this so that the output is within the same powershell shell?

What's odd is that if I execute the command directly, it shows up the way I want it. So something like:

```
C:\myCommand.bat $args
```

Given that I need to choose which command I want to run at runtime, how do I make it so the output is in the same shell when I use the '&' to execute the command in the variable? Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `Start-Process` with the `-NoNewWindow` parameter instead of `&`:

```
Start-Process -filepath C:\myCommand.bat -argumentList @("arg1","arg2") -NoNewWindow
```

Comment: That did the trick. A couple of notes for people who may try this:

1.) The filepath has to include the extension. It is not good enough to have the var set to C:\foo, but it must be set to C:\foo.bat.

2.) This works a lot like adding the & to the end of a BASH command. To have the process called synchronously, you have to supply a -Wait argument.

3.) If you're just wanting to pass the args through, you can put $args instead of @("arg1", "arg2") since $args is a String[].

Comment: @JasonThompson everything true, i just specified the array because some people just make $args a string